# Working with normalized data in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Lets say I have these two entities, and an Account entity has an Address.

```
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Address1 { get; private set; }
    public string Address2 { get; private set; }
    public string Address3 { get; private set; } 
    public int PostalCodeId { get; private set; }

    public virtual PostalCode PostalCode { get; private set; }
}

public class PostalCode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }        
}
```

I'm using CQRS and have a command to changes address like so.

```
public bool ChangeAddress(int addressId, string line1, string line2, string line3, string zipCode)
{
    //do something here....
}
```

I'm struggling with how to manage this. Since we have normalized data, the address being changed may be used in say 5 places. There are 3 workflows we could apply here.

> 1. Simply change the address, meaning all 5 places would be using the updated address.
> 2. Prompt the user, letting them know this address is used in 5 places, and have them specify if they want to change all or just this one (a lot more work).
> 3. Change just the address for this specific account, thus meaning we have 2 different addresses persisted in the db store now, the new one, and the old one which is now used in 4 places.

What is the preferred workflow (and yes, I know there is no correct answer, I"m wondering what is typically done)?

Once workflow is decided, how would this be implemented. For example, take case 1 from above. To implement the change I have to do the following:

> 1. Instantiate an address object in code using the parameters to the method.
> 2. Look in the DB to see if that address exists.
>
>    > a. [If Exists] - get Id of existing, set Account.AddressId = foundId
>    >     b. [If doesn't Exist] - use instantiated object and assign, Account.Address = newAddress, then .SaveChanges() and a new address record will be entered into the database.

..seems like a lot of work, but maybe it is what it is.

Furthermore, what if the user just changes the zip code on the address they are changing. I need to look to see if the "new" one exists in the DB first, then use its id. If it doesn't exist, instantiate a new object in code. The id will be 0 so EF sets EntityState.Inserted on .SaveChanges() a new record will be placed in the table. THEN... I have to look up the old one and if its not used anywhere anymore, remove it from the DB.

..even more work, but again, maybe it is what it is.

Am I missing something here, seems like things like this should be easier to do using the ORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An address does hardly ever change. Instead an entity (person, business, whatever) may move to a different address than currently registered.

So no, you should not want users to be able to edit addresses. You could let them link an entity to a new or different address.

Comment: So never edit an existing address record. Just create new ones. Should I remove the old address if nothing uses it anymore?

Comment: Only you can decide that. If relevant, you would want to keep them around  for historic purposes, for example so that an order sent to the current address will keep pointing to that address, even if the customer moves.

Answer (score 1):

When an address is changed (edited) then it should be for correction of the address, so it should change only at one place and be reflected everywhere it is referenced. IOW it should change in all those 5 places. If it were something unique to a person, say like an email address might be, then it wouldn't be on another table (entity).

Depending on needs it could be modeled as 1-to-1, 1-to-Many or Many-to-Many.

```
class Person
{
  public Address Address {get;set;}
}

class Person
{
  public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}

class Address
{
 ...
}

//or
class Address
{
 ...
 public virtual ICollection<Person> People {get;set;}
}
```